# One end of usb cable got wet while still plugged into an outlet

Tags: samsung, charging, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, water-damage

I have a galaxy s7 edge phone. The usb cable for charging, the end that plugs into the phone (I think it's called a connector) got sticky due to some food. I used an antibacterial liquid to clean it. Unfortunately I noticed too late that the other end is still plugged in to an outlet because I felt some electricity through the end. I panicked and quickly dried the end that plugs to the phone. After drying, I Immediately plugged in my phone. It charged without any problems.

Given what happened, is my phone and my usb cable still safe from harm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get a definitive answer but I would strongly  recommend using **not** using that cable any more

Reason being that the food matter and the anti bacterial liquid *may* have seeped a wee bit into the cable or form some conductance between the pins. Drying out fully is not easy unless you had used rubbing alcohol (isopropyl alcohol) which is generally recommended.

The fact that it is working fine now is no guarantee that you won't have a problem in future and replacing the cable is a small price to pay

Also see [How to physically clean a USB connector safely](https://superuser.com/q/391317/630136) from our SE.Superuser

**Edit** I was Googling and found this link from Samsung that suggests it's fine if you don't get a [moisture warning](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/USB_Charging_Warning.html) so you could take a chance and replace the cable earliest

Comment: I will not be able to buy another cable at this time. Until I can buy a new one, can I safely use this old cable before it breaks?

Comment: Please note that Samsung is talking of moisture in the charging port and your problem is with USB cable. I would still suggest you replace cable ASAP. Small price to pay to avoid problems

Comment: I'm curious, how can liquid get through the cable? I can't find any holes in the connector. Is it just too small? Also, I forgot to mention that the reason
I noticed it's still plugged in to an outlet is because there is a little electricity I felt while cleanning. Is this the conductance you are talking about?

Comment: I am also not sure if liquid can actually get in but being safe. Ideally one shouldn't feel any electricity when touching so maybe some thing to do with the cleaning agent used

Comment: Also remember that devices may be water proof rated but not cables - they needn't be. Nobody is expecting you to charge in rain :)